# disable volume buttons

Tags: buttons, volume-control

Problem at hand: I keep pressing volume button on my Nexus S when it is in my pocket. Most notably when playing music. More often than not it results in increasing volume, which is incredibly irritating.
Had exactly the same issue with Nexus One.

Desired solution: A tweak/app that simply disables volume button when the screen is off (or locked?)

I looked through the android market and found a few half baked solutions... I don't really need a widget or a prompt to revert volume change or a being have to run an extra app when I actually want to change volume.

Comment: Sorry for my initial answer, didn't finish reading the question!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a LOT with my Thunderbolt. The solution I went with was to buy a low-profile TPU case for it and I've LOVED this solution. Not exactly what you're asking for but it might be something to consider. I chose a $5 "S-Line" case from eBay that lots of people sell. It's great and adds a lot of protection at little cost and is as low-profile as you can get a case to be imho.

Answer (score 1):

While having the music player minimized, You could try running an app that "uses" the volume control hardware keys ( The only one im aware of is emulators that can map these keys to A and B buttons in SNES games etc.. ) When running those emulators, I noticed that I couldn't change the volume no longer and it only made my mario jump.

And emulators can suck up a lot of juice.. you might want to try running some other app that'd do the trick.. Since this type of hack is possible, im sure there is a possibility of making a very low battery consuming dummy app that does only the job of nullifying the volume controls..